# Is a mobile-compatible WebRTC application possible?

Tags: mobile, webrtc

The Mozilla Dev Network [shows that WebRTC MediaStream API is not currently supported in any mobile browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_API#Browser_compatibility), and I'm thinking "Hmm... who wants to write a web app these days useless on a mobile device?".

So is this accurate? Is there not some way to implement WebRTC in a mobile-compatible web application? Is this MDN info correct?

Answer (score 1):

not true.. chrome for android support it, and stock browser(which is chrome) on android 5.0+ you can see here relevant info:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection

with intel xdk crosswalk build you can get webrtc to work in android 4.0+.
to get it work with cordova on ios there is some plugins in github:

- https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc
- http://sipjs.com/guides/mobile/cordova/

and more

Answer (score 0):

That page looks outdated ufortunately, but it is also likely not where you want to look if you care primarily about camera access, as it covers the broader MediaStream API, which still has parts that are under development in most browsers, so it may not list things as supported until the entire API is covered.

For cameras, see [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) instead, which I know has been updated more recently.

WebRTC is a big piece of technology with [many pieces still in development](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com), so there isn't always a clear yes or no answer, but I know that WebRTC - including getUserMedia and RTCPeerConnection - is supported on at least Chrome for Android and Firefox for Android on mobile.